# Is there a content-filtering tool for native apps?

Tags: android, ios, iphone-app, website-blocker, content-filtering

Content-filtering browser add-ons like [KBlocker](http://kblocker.co/#key-features), [Trump Trump](http://trumptrump.co/) and [Trump Filter](http://trumpfilter.com/) allow for the filtering of content based on predefined keywords. Add-ons like [FB Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) and [Social Fixer](http://socialfixer.com/) go further and allow the user to specify custom keywords and filters to block. However, all of these are browser add-ons, and as a result are limited to working only on browsers, even during mobile browsing.

The most common way for mobile browsers to use social media like Facebook and Twitter is through their respective, native apps. Are there any content-filtering tools out there, *for any mobile operating system*, that will filter content from within these apps?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the developers of website-specific smartphone applications, such as Facebook, don't provide an extension mechanism for the application, nor its source code. So it can be difficult or impossible to modify the application to, e.g., block ads. This is likely one reason that websites aggressively promote their smartphone applications: it gives them much more control than the Web proper.

So, if you want to filter things on a website, you should probably stick to a real web browser.